# How to handle tap in two or more views in UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate

Tags: uikit, uicontextmenuinteraction

There are two views and there were added UIContextMenuInteraction to both views. After tap one of these views need to identify which view was tapped.

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
 let redView = UIView()
 let blueView = UIView()
...
func setup() {
 let interaction1 = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
 redView.addInteraction(interaction)
 
 let interaction2 = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
 blueView.addInteraction(interaction)
}

}

extension Cell: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {

 func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction,    configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider:    { suggestedActions in
            // How to here identify which view was tapped
            // if tapped redView -> show custom menu1
            // if tapped blueView -> show custom menu2
        })
    }
}
```

For one views it works fine. But for two ore more views there is difficulties with identifying which view were tapped

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter - `interaction` - in:

```
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
```

is a reference to the `UIContextMenuInteraction` object.

So, just as you have your two views as class properties, add two `UIContextMenuInteraction` vars as properties:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let redView = UIView()
    let blueView = UIView()

    var redInteraction: UIContextMenuInteraction!
    var blueInteraction: UIContextMenuInteraction!

    func setup() {
        redInteraction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
        redView.addInteraction(redInteraction)
        
        blueInteraction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
        blueView.addInteraction(blueInteraction)
    }
    
}
```

When the delegate is called, you can evaluate `interaction` to determine which one invoked the menu:

```
extension Cell: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {
    
    func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        
        if interaction == redInteraction {
            
            // redView context menu invoked
            
            let favorite = UIAction(title: "Red Favorite", image: UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")) { _ in
                // Perform action
            }
            
            let share = UIAction(title: "Red Share", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.fill")) { action in
                // Perform action
            }
            
            let delete = UIAction(title: "Red Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill"), attributes: [.destructive]) { action in
                // Perform action
            }
            
            return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
                UIMenu(title: "Red Actions", children: [favorite, share, delete])
            }
        }
        
        // blueView context menu invoked

        let share = UIAction(title: "Blue Share", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.fill")) { action in
            // Perform action
        }
        
        let delete = UIAction(title: "Blue Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill"), attributes: [.destructive]) { action in
            // Perform action
        }
        
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
            UIMenu(title: "Blue Actions", children: [share, delete])
        }
        
    }
    
}
```